# Change class of element on resize window

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, class, swiper.js

I search that resize event detect when i resizing the windows, and i know the widht o window can i get it using `window.innerWidth` or `innerWidht`

```
const swiperRooms = document.querySelector('#swiperRooms'); //this contain class mySwiper-rooms
addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    if(innerWidth < 834) swiperRooms?.classList.toggle('mySwiper');
});
```

I want to change the class of my swiper(slider) to other class that i have but i dont know why my code doesnt work. Its my first time doing resize

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your full code or not, but here are some things that might be the problem:

**Number One - Classes and IDs:**
Your comment in first line is saying "this contain `class mySwiper-rooms`" but in your querySelector you are using an ID `#swiperRooms`.  So check your html if

- a) are you using a class or ID? `class="swiperRooms"` or `id="swiperRooms"`
- b) is it `swiperRooms` or `mySwiper-rooms` ?

**Number Two - addEventListener:**
First of all, using `addEventListener()` just like you did is okay, as it's equivalent to `window.addEventListener()` and that's what you want.
Also the event `resize`to listen on is correct.

**Number Three - Logic inside eventListener:**
I'll assume you didn't create your `innerWidth` variable by yourself (using `var`, `const` or `let`), so this is okay as well since it's equal to `window.innerWidth`. But just in case, check if you have it defined somewhere yourself.
Toggling your class: In this case, I wouldn't recomment to toggle the class. Instead split the toggle into `classList.add` and `classList.remove`.
Why? Because if you are resizing your window, you will most probably see the `resize` event multiple times.

- Add the class: `if (innerWidth < 834)`
- Remove the class: `else`

---

In short:

- Check your classes and IDs if they are correct
- Don't toggle the class because `resize` event is firing multiple times, instead add and remove it depending on your window size.

---

Working example (not actual swiper, just colors), you have to resize your window until the iframe get's smaller.

```js
const swiperRooms = document.querySelector('.swiper-room');

addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
    console.log(innerWidth);

    if (innerWidth < 600) {
    swiperRooms.classList.add('mySwiper');
  }
  else {
    swiperRooms.classList.remove('mySwiper');
  }
});
```

```css
.swiper-room {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.swiper-room.mySwiper {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-room"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all some correctures:

```
const swiperRooms = document.querySelector('#swiperRooms'); //this contain class mySwiper-rooms
    window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
        if(window.innerWidth < 834) {
          swiperRooms.classList.toggle('mySwiper');
        }
    });
```

I think you want to add the class, if the window is smaller than in your case 834.
The problem is that you used toggle. Every time you resize the window, and the condition of < 834 is true, the class is toggled. Means that it is a 50%-chance to have this class active or not. Instead of using toggle you should use add. And if the condition is not true just remove the class. Like the following:

```
 if(window.innerWidth < 834) {
     swiperRooms.classList.add('mySwiper');
 }else{
     swiperRooms.classList.remove('mySwiper');
 }
```

But another thing i would throw into the room is, that you probably don't need this javascript. You should use instead css - media-querys.
For example in your css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 834px) {
  //here you need to specify elements and give properties
}
```

Simply select the css of your slider which you already gave some styles, and then change the properties to your wish. The media query will override the "normal" properties if the condition (max-width: 834px) is true.
Hope i could help.